# "I went into a restaurant, and the waiter..."

Tags: articles, general-vs-specific

"We went into a restaurant. And the waiter introduced us to seats upstairs."

In this sentence, when the speaker said "the waiter," does it necessarily mean there was only one waiter and he/she showed them the way to upstairs?

"We went into a restaurant. And the waiter in black tuxedo with a red necktie introduced us to seats upstairs."

Is this sentence, on the other hand, telling the reader that there was either only that waiter alone or several waiters were there but that particular waiter led them to the seats?

Comment: What is your question - change the _the_ to _a_ in the first sentence and there may be more waiters. Now there is only one

Comment: @mplungjan, no, it is common to say "the waiter" even if there are many waiters, referring to *the* one, individual waiter, who was *serving us* (or our table). The first sentence does not limit the number of waiters in the restaurant in any way. In fact, the context of "a restaurant" already sets the expectation that there is (likely) more than one waiter, and that's how I read the first sentence ("*We went into a restaurant, and **our** waiter sat us upstairs*"). It's of course possible it's a small restaurant with only one waiter, but "*the waiter*" provides no information either way.

Comment: Both of those sets of sentences are very very awkward.  *The waiter* is the least of your worries.

Comment: Usually, it's *"the host"* or *"the hostess"* who seats people in a restaurant. The *"waiter"* takes your order and brings you your food.

Comment: Seats, this is user user89068.  user89068, this is my good friend Seats Upstairs.

Answer (score 2):

'The waiter' as a subject means that only one waiter performed the action in question - leading you upstairs to a table.  There might be a dozen other waiters who did not do this, or only one waiter in the establishment.  The sentence says nothing about that.

If several waiters collectively led you to your table, then the sentence is in error.

Comment: This would certainly be my interpretation too, based on British usage and practice.